# Praying to the Avot?

Tags: tefilla, avodah-zarah, avot-patriarch-fathers, oral-torah

In the Oral tradition, it appears to be people who pray to their forefathers and foremothers, like Yousef begging Rochela Imeinu at her grave to save him from the Midianyim, and Calev went to the Kever Machpelah and basically prayed to the Avot to ask HaShem that he be "delivered from the spies' plan". Are they really praying to their forefathers and foremothers?? Is that even allowed? Is it avodah zarah to ask our forefathers for things like they do?

Comment: Note that the accepted answer there has 7 downvotes and a net score of -1. For one reason why, see [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/do-jews-pray-to-deceased-forefathers?rq=1#comment178020_44720). For another reason why, see [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33627/do-jewish-people-believe-in-god#comment85790_33633) and subsequent comments on a different question.

Comment: Related: (but dealing with live humans, rather than dead humans): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62638/asking-a-human-to-interecede-with-god